# Most Man of the match Awards in IPL

Tags: cricket, indian-premier-league

Which player have the most man of the match award record in IPL (Indian Premier League)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to Wikipedia's [List of Indian Premier League records and statistics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Indian_Premier_League_records_and_statistics), Chris Gayle has the most MOM awards, at 17. See the "Miscellaneous records" section.